# show date in proper format

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have date stored in mysql database in a varchar field in format YYYYMMDD for example 20130312. I know the proper way should have been to use either date or timestamp datatype but that is something not in my hand now.

I want to show this data in proper format using date() function on my web page, in php. How do I do it.

using

```
date("Y-m-d", strtotime('20130312'))
```

doesn't works. Any help!

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean exactly? What result are you getting?

Comment: Exactly which result you want ?

Comment: try  echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime('20130312'));

Comment: `Select...DATE_FORMAT(datecolumn,"%Y-%m-%d ")`

Comment: *Why* can you not convert the type of your column?  Conversion should be extremely straightforward and, given that your existing format is a valid [MySQL date literal format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-literals.html), your existing codebase should remain compatible.  The change ought to be as simple as `ALTER TABLE foo CHANGE mycol mycol DATE`.

Comment: Your example yields "2013-03-12". What is not desired about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `DATE`

```
SELECT DATE(20130312)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/8841)

But if you want to return in this format `YYYY/MM/DD`, use `DATE_FORMAT()` (*it returns a string*)

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE(20130312), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/8842)

OTHER SOURCE:

- [DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date)
- [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Answer (score 1):

There is a function called "DATE_FORMAT(date,format)" to convert dates in different formats.
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp

```
 DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%b %d %Y %h:%i %p')
 DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m-%d-%Y')
 DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%d %b %y')
 DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%d %b %Y %T:%f')
```

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
   <?php   
   $dbdate = '20130312';
   $year  = substr($dbdate,'0','4');
   $month = substr($dbdate,'4','2');
   $date  = substr($dbdate,'6','2');
   $formatDate = "$year-$month-$date";
   echo $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($formatDate))
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to convert to a timestamp, use

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(20130312) date_as_timestamp
```

from MySQL before processing with PHP, eg

```
date('some format like dd/mm/YYYY', $row['date_as_timestamp'])
```